# I can't select a specific button in javascript whereas it's there and exists

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm on a project so I'm making a website.
My problem is that when I try to select and add a click event on a specific button it doesn't work whereas the button for sur exists and that works with other buttons.
The buttons that I can't select is the btn1EventClick and btn2EventClick
Here is my code:

HTML:

```html
    <div id="products">
        <div class="product-1">
            <div class="fourchette">
                <h2>Fourchette enrouleuse de spaghetti</h2>
                <img src="fourchette.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="btn1"><button></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-2">
            <div class="btn2"><button></button></div>
            <div class="cuillere">
                <h2>Cuillère mélangeuse de yahourt</h2>
                <img src="cuillere.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="default-html-p1">
        <div class="fourchette">
            <h2>Fourchette enrouleuse de spaghetti</h2>
            <img src="fourchette.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="btn1"><button></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="default-html-p2">
        <div class="btn2"><button></button></div>
            <div class="cuillere">
                <h2>Cuillère mélangeuse de yahourt</h2>
                <img src="cuillere.png" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="click-event-btn1">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btn2"><button></button></div>
    </div>

    <div class="click-event-btn2">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btn1"><button></button></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector('.product-1 .btn1');
let btn2 = document.querySelector('.product-2 .btn2');
let fourchette = document.querySelector('#products .product-1 img[src="fourchette.png"]')
let cuillere = document.querySelector('#products .product-2 img[src="cuillere.png"]')
let products = document.getElementById('products');
let product1 = document.querySelector('#products .product-1');
let product2 = document.querySelector('#products .product-2');
let clickEventbtn1 = document.querySelector('.click-event-btn1');
let clickEventbtn2 = document.querySelector('.click-event-btn2');
let btn1EventClick = document.querySelector('.click-event-btn2 .btn1 button');
let btn2EventClick = document.querySelector('.click-event-btn1 .btn2 button');
let defaultHtmlProduct1 = document.querySelector('.default-html-p1')

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        product2.innerHTML = clickEventbtn1.innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('.btn2 button').style.position = "absolute";
        document.querySelector('.btn2 button').style.right = "110px";
        document.querySelector('.btn2 button').style.bottom = "5vh";
        btn1.style.display = "none";
        fourchette.style.animation = "rotateanim 1.5s linear";
        products.style.columnGap = "0";
})

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        product1.innerHTML = clickEventbtn2.innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('.btn1 button').style.position = "absolute";
        document.querySelector('.btn1 button').style.left = "110px";
        document.querySelector('.btn1 button'). style.bottom = "5vh";
        btn2.style.display = "none";
        cuillere.style.animation = "rotateanim 1.5s linear forwards";
        products.style.columnGap = "0";
})

btn1EventClick.addEventListener('click', () => {
    product1.innerHTML = defaultHtmlProduct1.innerHTML;
})
```

Can you please tell where is the problem cause I've been trying to find it out for hours now.

Comment: What specifically doesn’t work??? Do btn1EventClick and btn2EventClick actually make sense?

Comment: "When I try to select and add a click event on a specific button" which one? You posted several for some reason, how are we supposed to know? "It doesn't work" what doesn't work? Error message?  "Whereas the button for sur (sic) exists" how do you know this?

Comment: sorry your right that's the btn1EventClick button that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that you add listeners to DOM elements then replace them wth other elements.

You have (cutting out the fat)

```
let btn1 = document.querySelector('.product-1 .btn1'); //Get btn1 dom node
let product1 = document.querySelector('#products .product-1'); //Get product one dom node
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {}); //add event to btn1 dom node
let defaultHtmlProduct1 = document.querySelector('.default-html-p1');
product1.innerHTML = defaultHtmlProduct1.innerHTML;//replace everything in product1 with new html.
```

At the end, btn1 is a non existent dom node, beacause it was replaced by a new dom node, although with same name but it is not quite the exact same object.

You'd need to rebind the events to the different nodes when you replace them, but also refetch the nodes themselves.